# Is Tor for android secure?: will it hide my real IP and device info?

Tags: ip-address

I am new at tor. I want to use it on my android to visit websites but I don't want the site admins to know my real IP or my device (android) info. Sorry if I am totally misunderstanding this whole thing, but will Tor prevent the sites from knowing what my android serial # is, what brand of android phone I use, stuff like that? Can they know any info about my device?

Answer (score 1):

No one can make a 100% guarantee of these things, and generally speaking the question "Is x secure?" or "Is x safe?" is only even meaningful in the context of *"...against y"*.

If programs use Tor incorrectly and don't respect your privacy or weren't designed for anonymity, they may reveal both your IP and information about your device.

1. Use only trust*worthy* programs, which make a good-faith effort to preserve your anonymity. *(Are they open-source? Do they give warnings about misuse and guides on how to use them properly? Do they fix bugs?)*
2. Use `iptables` to block accidental or malicious leaks of packets outside of tor.